# Load testing for Login and Logout for js application

Tags: javascript, load, protractor

I have a need where I need to login to my application and load the home page and logout. I need to load the homepage 200-300 times to make sure It doesn't timeout.

I have been running protractor tests for this js application. I run concurrent test run with Max of 5 sessions.

I came across this below and seems like it is just for the URL. My need is to load the URL - Login - Logout .

https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest

Can someone advise

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it with simple for loop.

```
for (var i = 100 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

 it('Should enter homepage url', function() {
  browser.get('/#/');

});

    // //Get the login page test:

 Login.test()
 logout.test()`
```